# Binding to an associated value of an enum

Tags: swift, swiftui

Is there a standard way to bind, say, a `TextField` to an associated value of an enum?

So, given this:

```
enum Choice {
  case one(String)
  case two(String)
}
```

Can I use it in some way as a binding in the View:

```
@State var choice: Choice = .one("")

var body: some View {
   TextField("", text: $choice) // <- this clearly wouldn't work
}
```

Such that if `choice` was set to `choice = .one("")`, then TextField would update the associated value of `one`.

**EDIT**

To clarify, can just the associated value of each be bound, so if the `choice` variable is `.one`, then `.one`'s associated value would change; same with `.two`, and so forth.

Comment: I don't think I said that. I meant, if the enum variable is equal to `.one("whatever")`, the TextField would update the associated value (i.e. the `"whatever"`) part, but keep the `.one` part

Comment: @LeoDabus, whichever the value the enum was set to initially. If it was `.two`, then it would update the associated value of the `.two` case. I could do that a switch statement of all the cases, but is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: @LeoDabus - yeah, that seems like an elegant approach. Can you post as an answer, and I'll accept

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can extend your enumeration and add a text property with a getter and a setter:

```
extension Choice {
    var text: String {
        get {
            switch self {
            case let .one(string): return string
            case let .two(string): return string
            }
        }
        set {
            switch self {
            case .one: self = .one(newValue)
            case .two: self = .two(newValue)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can simply pass the text property:

```
TextField("", text: $choice.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a demo of possible solution. Tested with Xcode 11.4

```
struct TestBindToCase: View {
    @State var choice: Choice = .one("")

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ChoiceField
            Divider()
            Button("Assign") { self.choice = .one("Unknown") }
        }
    }

    var ChoiceField: some View {
        let boundCase = Binding(
            get: {
                if case let .one(value) = self.choice {
                    return value
                } else { return "" }
            },
            set: { self.choice = .one($0) })
        return TextField("", text: boundCase)   // << works
    }
}
```