# Binding to an associated value of an enum that has different types of associated values

Tags: swift, swiftui

Followup question to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62227525/2396481).

What if:

```
enum Choice {
  case one(String)
  case two(String)
}
```

is instead:

```
enum Choice {
  case one(String)
  case two(Bool)
}
```

and in my view I'm switching on the enum and then binding one case's associated value to, say, a text field, and the other, to a toggle? A [computed String property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62227525/2396481) won't do the trick for me now in the case where I need to bind to the bool.

All I can think is to copy & paste the property and change all the `String` to `Bool` but in my real code I have lots of different types so that approach is getting pretty stupid looking.

Any ideas would be appreciated, thanks!

Current code:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @StateObject private var model = Model()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(model)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var model: Model
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView {
                Text(model.jsonString)
            }
            
            List($model.data, id: \.name, children: \.children) { $node in
                HStack {
                    switch node.value {
                    case .none:
                        Spacer()
                    case .bool:
                        Toggle(node.name, isOn: $node.value.bool)
                    case let .int(value):
                        Stepper("\(value)", value: $node.value.int)
                    case let .float(value):
                        Text(value.description)
                    case let .string(value):
                        Text(value)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var data: [Node] = [
        Node(name: "My Bool", value: .bool(false)),
        Node(name: "My Int", value: .int(25)),
        Node(name: "My float", value: .float(3.123)),
        Node(name: "My parent node", value: .none, children: [
            Node(name: "Default name", value: .string("Untitled")),
            Node(name: "Fluid animations", value: .bool(true)),
            Node(name: "More children??", value: .none, children: [
                Node(name: "Hello", value: .string("There"))
            ])
        ])
    ]
    
    private let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    
    init() {
        encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
    }
    
    var jsonString: String {
        String(data: try! encoder.encode(data), encoding: .utf8)!
    }
}

struct Node: Codable {
    var name: String
    var value: Value
    var children: [Node]? = nil
}

enum Value: Codable {
    case none
    case bool(Bool)
    case int(Int)
    case float(Float)
    case string(String)
    
    
    var bool: Bool {
        get {
            switch self {
            case let .bool(value): return value
            default: fatalError("Unexpected value \(self)")
            }
        }
        set {
            switch self {
            case .bool: self = .bool(newValue)
            default: fatalError("Unexpected value \(self)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    var int: Int {
        get {
            switch self {
            case let .int(value): return value
            default: fatalError("Unexpected value \(self)")
            }
        }
        set {
            switch self {
            case .int: self = .int(newValue)
            default: fatalError("Unexpected value \(self)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    var float: Float {
        get {
            switch self {
            case let .float(value): return value
            default: fatalError("Unexpected value \(self)")
            }
        }
        set {
            switch self {
            case .float: self = .float(newValue)
            default: fatalError("Unexpected value \(self)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    var string: String {
        get {
            switch self {
            case let .string(value): return value
            default: fatalError("Unexpected value \(self)")
            }
        }
        set {
            switch self {
            case .string: self = .string(newValue)
            default: fatalError("Unexpected value \(self)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Update: Added code below that I ended up with after changes from answer and working around a weird swiftui animation thing.

```
import SwiftUI

enum Value: Codable, Equatable {
    case none
    case bool(Bool)
    case int(Int)
    case float(Float)
    case string(String)
}

struct Node: Codable {
    var name: String
    var value: Value
    var children: [Node]? = nil
}

struct ValueView: View {
    let name: String
    @Binding var value: Value
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            switch value {
            case .none:
                Spacer()
            case let .bool(bool):
                Toggle(name, isOn: Binding(get: { bool }, set: { value = .bool($0) } ))
            case let .int(int):
                Stepper("\(int)", value: Binding(get: { int }, set: { value = .int($0) }))
            case let .float(float):
                Text(float.description)
            case let .string(string):
                Text(string)
            }
        }
    }
}

class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var data: [Node] = [
        Node(name: "My Bool", value: .bool(false)),
        Node(name: "My Int", value: .int(25)),
        Node(name: "My float", value: .float(3.123)),
        Node(name: "My parent node", value: .none, children: [
            Node(name: "Default name", value: .string("Untitled")),
            Node(name: "Fluid animations", value: .bool(true)),
            Node(name: "More children??", value: .none, children: [
                Node(name: "Hello", value: .string("There"))
            ])
        ])
    ]
    
    private let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    
    init() {
        encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
    }
    
    var jsonString: String {
        String(data: try! encoder.encode(data), encoding: .utf8)!
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var model = Model()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView {
                Text(model.jsonString)
            }
            
            List($model.data, id: \.name, children: \.children) { $node in
                ValueView(name: node.name, value: $node.value)
                    .animation(.default, value: node.value)
            }
        }
    }
}

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @StateObject private var model = Model()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a very bad idea! Please paste the current code.

Comment: @Jessy added current code

Comment: @Cristik no not trying to avoid any switch statements, just the super redundant computed properties in the `Value` enum.

Comment: @Cristik ah ok well, I'll probably stick with this then since polymorphism would probably involve even more lines of code to work with Codable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, having several very similar properties is a code smell, as well as the fact that those properties were added just because they are needed by the UI layer.

However, since you already have the switch over the value type, you can push the logic for the binding to that (UI) layer. Here's a possible implementation:

```swift
struct ValueView: View {
    let name: String
    @Binding var value: Value
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            switch value {
            case .none:
                Spacer()
            case let .bool(bool):
                Toggle(name, isOn: Binding(get: { bool }, set: { value = .bool($0) } ))
            case let .int(int):
                Stepper("\(int)", value: Binding(get: { int }, set: { value = .int($0) }))
            case let .float(float):
                Text(float.description)
            case let .string(string):
                Text(string)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also took the liberty of extracting the code to a dedicated view and decoupling that view from the `Node` type, this is more idiomatic in SwiftUI and makes your code more readable and easier to maintain.

With the above in mind, `ContentView` simply becomes:

Usage:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var model = Model()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView {
                Text(model.jsonString)
            }
            
            List($model.data, id: \.name, children: \.children) { $node in
                ValueView(name: node.name, value: $node.value)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

, and you can safely delete the "duplicated" properties from the `Value` enum.

Comment: Thanks so much man!! I love this! If you’re bored and want another challenge lol, I was also trying to figure out how in the world I could move the children in Node over to the Value enum as just another case but somehow still work with List’s children keypath argument. I’ve had no luck so far but it would sure be cool if there was a way to do it I think. :D actually I’ll make a new question for that so it’s of more use to everyone if it gets answered.

Comment: @FrankTinsley not sure it would make sense to move the `children` property to the enum. The enum has a well-defined role of representing multiple types of values. You could convert `Node` into an enum, but I'd say the `Value` enum should be kept.

Comment: The thing is I never actually wanted Nodes to be able to have values AND children. If they have children then that is their value, at least, in my ideal mental model.

Comment: @FrankTinsley if you really want only one enum, you could have two associated values, the  `children` being the second, however, you'd also need to add the `name` there, so you'll end up with a lot of repetitions.

Comment: Started new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72493645/using-list-with-children-inside-an-enums-associated-value

Comment: Shoot actually I just tested your code and it looks like it's causing SwiftUI performance to breakdown somehow (note the way the toggle performs before and after). Could it be from the views rebuilding the Bindings too often?
Wait... the rest of the UI seems to stay smooth... wtf?

Comment: Fixed: just needed to specify that our new ValueView should be animated by adding `.animation(.default, value: node.value)` and conforming Value to Equatable automagically.

Comment: @FrankTinsley how about the `name`? You'd still have to carry that information to multiple enum cases.

Comment: Glad you fixed the performance issue, btw.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245331/discussion-between-frank-tinsley-and-cristik).